# Disabling radio button in jsp based on map value struts2

Tags: struts, radio-button

I'm trying to use a boolean value returned from a map in my bean to either disable/enable a radio button in a jsp page.

Class snippet:

```
public class Options{
   private String optionId;
   private Map<String,Boolean> negativeMap;

   public setNegativeMap(Map<String,Boolean> negativeMap){

   .......

}
```

JSP snippet:

```
<input id="radioClick<s:property value=optionId"/> type="radio" disabled="%{negativeMap[optionId]}" />
```

Am I on the right track with this? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please, I think your JSP snippet was wrong near "value=optionId"/>" :

```
<input id="radioClick<s:property value=optionId"/> type="radio" disabled="%{negativeMap[optionId]}" />
```

Your JSP snippet should be like this :

```
<input id="radioClick<s:property value=optionId/>" type="radio" disabled="%{negativeMap[optionId]}" />
```